# Using NtAllocateVirtualMemory() via GetProcAddress will not compile

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use NtAllocateVirtualMemory for a project and I'm sure others have had success w/it, but this will not compile on VSC++ 2010 nor mingw. On both compilers it says

FARPROC: too many arguments for call

Does anyone know how I can get this code to compile? Thanks for your time.

```
FARPROC NtAllocateVirtualMemory;

NtAllocateVirtualMemory = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("NTDLL.DLL"), "NtAllocateVirtualMemory");

printf( "NtAllocateVirtualMemory %08x\n", NtAllocateVirtualMemory);

ReturnCode = NtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),
                                     &BaseAddress,
                                     0,
                                     &RegionSize,
                                     MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
                                     PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to cast the result from `GetProcAddress` to a function pointer of the correct type. In this case:

```
typedef NTSTATUS WINAPI (*PNtAllocateVirtualMemory)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, 
                                                    PVOID *BaseAddress, 
                                                    ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, 
                                                    PSIZE_T RegionSize,
                                                    ULONG AllocationType, 
                                                    ULONG Protect);

FARPROC NAVM = GetProcAddress(...);
PNtAllocateVirtualMemory NtAllocateVirtualMemory = (PNtAllocateVirtualMemory)NAVM;

...
```

Of course, it would be much easier to simply use `VirtualAlloc`.

```
VirtualAlloc(&BaseAddress, RegionSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
             PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, thats not the answer though. the problem is was using a C++ compiler instead of C, stupid me!

Comment: Or you weren't turning up warnings high enough on your C compiler... FARPROC is a generic type that matches "any" function. But unfortunately that also means that the compiler can't even know when you are passing the wrong type (or when it needs to extend 0 from 32 to 64 bits for `ULONG_PTR`), so even in C, this is a very unreliable "solution".

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything. "In C, the FARPROC declaration indicates a callback function that has an unspecified parameter list. In C++, however, the empty parameter list in the declaration indicates that a function has no parameters. This subtle distinction can break careless code." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You clearly don't understand what I'm saying. If you use "unspecified parameters", the arguments are passed based on what the compiler thinks they should be - so the value 0 in your case would be 32-bits wide. In this particular case you won't notice, since it is in the first four arguments are passed in registers, and x86-64 automagically fills the upper 32-bits with the sign extension of the lower 32 bits. But it would matter in a function where the 5th argument is 32 or 64 bits based on pointer size. In other words, DON'T rely on "arbitrary arguments".

Comment: In other words, it might compile, but it won't run (except by happy coincidence).

Comment: Or even worse, it may appear to work all the way until you pass an argument where the 31st bit is set, and you are all of a sudden getting a 0xFFFFFFF80000000 instead of 0x0000000080000000 that you intended - despite the value being an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Rodney compiling as C to allow compiler type inference is categorically not the solution here

Comment: The MS article already explains this fine. And no, I did the same thing for a call to DbgPrint() w/10 arguments, all pointers, and all it does is push pointers as arguments on to the stack. Everything worked fine. As the MS article already states, they have diff. properties in C and C++. That's the answer to this question, not yours. Thanks again for your help but I'm now finished here and wish you luck.

Comment: @David, it was a C project to begin with, not a C++ project. Thanks again guys, goodbye.

Comment: @rodney In C you should cast the return of GetProcAddress to a function pointer with the correct arguments and calling convention.

Comment: @Mats I think that this function is NTAPI which is `__stdcall` right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I would expect so. In 64-bit it wouldn't matter. In 32-bit it certainly does. @Rodney: They saying goes, you can lead a horse to water, but not force it to drink. You are clearly not WANTING to know the answer to your question, as long as you quickly find some solution. And yes, pointers will be passed correctly, because they change from 32 to 64 bits when you switch mode. It's integer constants without decorations, such as 0, 42, 0x800000000, or `int x = 2;` and then passing `x` where the code wants a `uintptr_t` or similar that causes problems.

Comment: I have updated to `WINAPI` - although the MSDN website seems to be lacking in that detail.

Comment: @Mats I think you need to go to the header file to find out. Of course once you are prepared to do that then you can use the header and the lib. VirtualAlloc looks good too......

Comment: Not actually having a single windows machine in my home (and only a virtual one, with no dev tools at work) makes that kind of hard. But everything OS-related is WINAPI, isn't it. But going through MS's website here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx about half of them are, and half aren't.